# Download Client with Resume Ability

Tags: linux, gratis, download-manager

I use Linux (Fedora, to be specific), and I have a huge problem where my ISP drops my Internet connection for a few seconds if I use bandwidth for too long (like downloading something). This will stop the download, and all of the download clients I have used get really messed up when this happens.

I am trying to find a download client/manager that is capable of *resuming* a download, or refreshing the connection, if there is no connection.

Requirements:

- Must work in Linux
- Must be free
- Can be program or in command line
- Must be able to automatically restart the download starting where the connection dropped (or allow this to be done very easily manually)
- It would be nice if it was open source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your ISP does is to drop your Internet connection, your downloads will be slightly delayed but not interrupted. This resilience is built into the [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) protocol. However, there's a chance that your ISP is doing more. If it is being naughty and sending RST packets on your behalf, or if it forces you to go through a transparent HTTP proxy, or if the disconnection causes your IP address to change, then your downloads will be aborted and there's nothing you can do about that.

You can resume an HTTP(S) download where it left off, but this requires support from the server. Some do, some don't; the only way to see is to try.

The two basic command line tools for downloading files (often preinstalled, but if not available in your distribution's package repository) support resuming downloads:

- With [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html), add the [`-c` (`--continue`)](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-continue-retrieval) option. This has no effect if there is no local file yet; if there is a local file, `wget` assumes that it's a partial download and attempts to resume where it left off.
  You may want to use the [`--content-disposition`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-Content_002dDisposition) option to use the server-specified name for the file. You may also want to specify a different [user agent string](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-user_002dagent) to avoid ill-advised “protections” on the server.

  ```
  wget --user-agent=Mozilla --content-disposition -c http://download.example.com/foo.zip
  ```
- With [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html), add `-C -` (`--continue-at -`) to the command line get the same effect as wget's `-c` option.

  ```
  curl --user-agent=Mozilla --remote-header-name -C - http://download.example.com/foo.zip
  ```

Both wget and curl can retry downloads if they get interrupted. Whether this is effective depends on how long you remain disconnected. See `--tries` and `--waitretry` options for wget, and the `--retry` and `--retry-delay` options for curl.

Some GUI download managers support resuming downloads; I think the major browsers don't.

If the server doesn't support resuming, you're stuck without an external relay.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Firefox with [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) extension. It has a nice GUI.

> DownThemAll (or just dTa) is a powerful yet easy-to-use Mozilla Firefox extension that adds new advanced download capabilities to your browser.
>   DownThemAll lets you download all the links or images contained in a webpage and much more: you can refine your downloads by fully customizable criteria to get only what you really want.
>   DownThemAll is all you can desire from a download manager: it features an advanced accelerator that increases speed up to 400%, it allows you to pause and resume downloads at any time.

From http://www.downthemall.net/

Here is a screenshot from its website (note that it is multiplatform):
[image]